# Ideal Design for handling combination of lots of inserts and queries concurrently

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, concurrency

Ok, first of all, I know people will say "depends on the data, the server hardware, etc..."

I am building a system where clients connect in and send me data.  This data gets processed and then a lot of rows are inserted into MySQL.  At the same time, users can use our web-ui to run queries against the data.  Sometimes the queries are too slow to return results (100 - 200 seconds).  I know there are probably some index-optimization and other things we can do, but I believe part of the problem is the competition between all the inserts and the user submitted select queries.

Is there a common infrastructure architecture/design that is used in this situation to improve performance?  For example, I have thought about having two mysql instances where the master receives all the inserts and the slave handles the queries, but would this suffer less from locks and contention or would this be mostly the same as having a single mysql instance?  I'm not an expert on databases and large datasets so any resources you can provide would be very helpful.  I have the High Performance MySQL book but I'm hoping to gain some insights from the community.

16 GB ram, 8 CPUs, ubuntu, about 10 GB of data right now but growing rather fast.  Using innodb but will probably start using Percona Server soon just to see if it improves things at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cache inserts in a memory table**
If you can get away with it, you can have the clients insert into a separate `MEMORY` table first, and then update these in a batch with `INSERT DELAYED`.

This will speed up your inserts, because:

1. There's less I/O traffic you're using the memory table as a ram-cache.
2. By grouping inserts into the on-disk table you're saving on I/O cost.
3. By doing `INSERT DELAYED` you're prioritizing SELECTS over INSERTS.
4. You can choose the timing to do the `INSERT`'s (maybe at night?)

You can do the same for UPDATES.

**By default MySQL is tuned for small memory sizes and small tables**
Make sure you review your settings make use of all that RAM. In the default setup MySQL will only use a fraction of your RAM.

**SELECT's and INSERT's are running on a single thread**
A single `SELECT` or `INSERT` will only ever use one thread.
With 8 CPU at 4 cores each you can run at least 32 threads at the same time without any CPU bottleneck.
If you have few selects running concurrenly, it might be worthwhile to install 2 MySQL instances (on separate ports) on a single machine in a master-slave setup.
This is not a usual use case though as normally many selects/inserts will be running at the same time. Test to see if all your cores are running.

**Time your selects and use explain**
To see if MySQL is using the proper indexes the way you've imagined them.

**Make your primary index as short as possible**
MySQL's InnoDB includes the primary key as a covering index on each and every secondary index, so make sure your PK is short. An INTEGER is usually a good choice.

**Links:**
INSERT DELAYED: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html
Config tuning: http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-optimization-and-tuning-guide.html
Config tuning 2: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/
EXPLAIN: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

Comment: I have already optimized it (at least I think I have done it properly) to use the 16 GB of RAM (and immediately saw a lot of benefit).  I have spent quite a bit of time on indexes but will continue to investigate these.  I will look into how many CPUs we are taking advantage of and will contemplate the master/slave setup.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've normally done this through a Master/Slave database architecture setup. The Master DB handles the actually Inserts and basic selects, while the Slave DB is what analytics tracking actually occurs off of.

Edit:

> What makes the slave faster (other
>   than presumably running on different
>   hardware)? Is it because the updates
>   from master -> slave are more like
>   bulk updates rather than lots of
>   insert statements?

It depends on how you set it really. It can either execute statements retrieved from the binlog, or simply add changed rows. Which of these you wish to use depends on how many inserts are generally done in a specific timeframe. I'd recommend looking over how MySQL replication works behind the scenes:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-implementation.html

> How often does your master sync with slave?

Unfortunately this setup was at a previous job where I didn't have enough access to know that information, so I don't have an answer to this.

Comment: What makes the slave faster (other than presumably running on different hardware)? Is it because the updates from master -> slave are more like bulk updates rather than lots of insert statements? How often does your master sync with slave?

Comment: @Ben Since the reply was a bit lengthy, I've included it inline.

Answer (score 0):

Using InnoDB is a good first step: it prevents table locking when inserts occur.